# jQuery - get child element of elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <span class="text"></span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <span class="text"></span>
</div>
<div id="div3">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <span class="text"></span>
</div>
<div id="div4">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <span class="text"></span>
</div>
```

Then I have some business logic in JavaScript do decide what div elements to put in array:

```
var arr = [];
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  if(someExpression) arr.push($("#div" + i));
}
```

The question: Is it possible to get all spans with class "text" from elements in arr (without using `$(arr).each` or `for` loop)?

I tried a simple things below, but they don't work..

```
$(arr).find(".text");
$(".text", $(arr));
$(".text", arr);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting jQuery objects into an array instead of a jQuery collection?

Comment: The example I showed is very simplified. Actually I work with angular directives and I manage the array of "$elements" in some helper service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of jQuery objects, that's why you can't create a jQuery object from the array.

Put the elements in the array instead:

```
var arr = [];
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  if(someExpression) arr.push($("#div" + i)[0]);
}
```

Then you can create a jQuery object from the array, and using `find` works fine to find the elements:

```
var texts = $(arr).find(".text");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Wu92L/

Answer (score 3):

You can use a disguised loop :

```
var texts = arr.map(function(div){ return div.find('.text') });
```

Starting from your existing `arr` array, there's not really a way to avoid a kind of loop.

But note that it would simpler to do

```
var texts = $('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4').find('.text');
```

or if you don't have other divs whose id starts with `div` :

```
var texts = $('[id^=div] .text');
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like there no choice except of using some kind of loop. Thanks

Comment: @AlexDn What's the problem with loops ? Any time you do something there are a lot of hidden loops involved.

Comment: No problem with loops, just thought I can use the "hidden" jQuery loop instead of writing my own...

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just select all div.text?

`var arr = $(".text");`

Comment: It not helps me so much, you missed the point...I don't need all ".text", i need the text from specific divs only.

Comment: well, you need loops or in the wrost case, you can do it with recursion.